# Angular 7 - Install local library (not published) - Project setup

Tags: angular, npm, angular-library

I have an Angular app, with a core module, and shared module.
My architecture is like that :

```
./repo
  | projects
    | core
    | shared
  | src (my app)
```

When I build libraries, the output folder is dist-lib/*
When I build app, the output folder is dist/*

So I used npm install to include my libs in my app :
- "core": "file:./dist-lib/core"
- "shared": "file:./dist-lib/shared"

All works fine but I have a problem when someone when to setup the project. Project can't 'npm install' because of the libraries not found (dist-lib/core not found...) and I can't build libraries because I have no ng-packager installed (need the npm install).

I tried to put core & shared in optionalDependencies. Nothing better.

I could move my libraries in an other angular app, but it's not funny.

Someone ?

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is with npm dependencies (in essence it has nothing to do with Angular). To solve this, you could either publish the modules on npm (which you probable don't want to do) or publish them on a private repository.

A detailed guide for the latter solution can be found here:
https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/registry

This way you can host your modules on your own computer/server. After you've added the private repository to your package.json you can add them as your dependencies as if they were normal npm packages.

Comment: I use git + ssh to publish and install private packages.

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to publish because libraries are in development.

So I finally found the problem. It was the package-lock.json trying to probably check packages version...

So my final command to setup the project is (with core & shared libraries in optionalDeps):

rimraf ./package-lock.json && npm install && npm run build:core && npm run build:shared && npm install

- Delete .package-lock.json
- npm install without libraries
- build core and shared libraries
- npm install libraries